# DateTime Parser error in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, parsing, datetime

```
t_info.solutionTime = Convert.ToDateTime(context.Request.QueryString["solutionDate"] == null ? "" : context.Request.QueryString["solutionDate"]);
```

Iam trying to convert the date format but it return this exception always

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

date in this format :  `2015-08-25 18:45:55`

Comment: Is that format valid in the locale of the running server?

Comment: @Steve I believe that is an unambiguous format and so does not depend on the server locale.

Comment: Depending on the circumstances, it might be an idea to fetch the result as **nullable** *DateTime*, i.e. *DateTime?*.

Answer (score 3):

Probably because `""` is not a valid date/time value.  You could use `DateTime.MinValue` or some other "magic" value to represent `null` instead:

```
t_info.solutionTime =
    context.Request.QueryString["solutionDate"] == null 
  ? DateTime.MinValue 
  : Convert.ToDateTime(context.Request.QueryString["solutionDate"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use DateTime.TryParse whenever you're not sure if an incoming value is a valid date.

```
DateTime possibleDateTime;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(context.Request.QueryString["solutionDate"], out possibleDateTime))
{
    //handle the situation where the parse fails
}

//if you get here you know there's a valid datetime in possibleDateTime
```

Comment: Note that `.ToString()` will fail here if the value isn't on the query string.

Comment: ^this, but you don't need to null check--the return type is already string so just take it off entirely. Anyway TryParse is the way to go here